# /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf file is missing in Ubuntu 18.04.01

Tags: server, 18.04, scripts

I'm creating a Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) template. Before I make a VM template, I adapt some files under /etc. However on 14.04 I had an file under /etc/init(not init.d)/rc-sysinit.

Actually I'm missinng the above mentioned /etc/init/rc-sysinit file. Has anyone any idea where it could be, or what happened, or what I should use instead. I've googled myself mad, but could not find anything useful.

Any help would be appreciated

Rgds

Haydar

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this file on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as it uses `systemd`.

Previous versions had `upstart` and this file was installed as a [part of it (see search results in packages.ubuntu.com)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=rc-sysinit.conf).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response:

I've to create this template accoring to instructions, however, I could not find this file under /etc/systemd. I'm looking especially for a certain part in this file:

"start on (filesystem and static-network-up) or failsafe-boot"

it was earlier in this rc-sysinit.conf file.

Thanks for all your help

Haydar